# XCUIElement getting underlying element object such as WebView

Tags: xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

Is there any way to capture the actual UI Cocoa object? IE:

```
let window = app.windows["mainScreen"]
let view = window.webViews["myWebView"]
let webView = view as! WebView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Xcode UI Testing runs in a separate process from the production application. There is no way to access any UI/Cocoa objects when running through these tests.

Comment: Thanks - my follow up question I can reformat this one - what's best approach to parse out the content of a WebView and read content when we have a XCUIElement object?

Comment: `XCUIApplication().staticTexts["content"]` or `.links["other"]` should work. Post a new question if you have something more specific and I'll help if I can. Also, I've written a little [UI Testing Cheat Sheet](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/) that answers some of these questions in more detail.

Comment: Given window.webViews["myWebView"], how would I extract out just the content of this view? The methods you pointed out seem to be at an app level.